# isCancelled() not Working in android Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download

I want to cancel a downloading file using async task, i tried below code, here isCancelled() method is not working, can any one suggest how can i stop download.

```
vid1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            down d1=new down();
        if(vid1.getText().toString().equals("Start")){
            Log.v("Vid 1", "Vid 1");
            vid1.setText("Pause");
            d1.execute(url1,"one");

        }else if(vid1.getText().toString().equals("Pause")){
            vid1.setText("Start");
            Log.v("Vid 1 Else", "Vid 1 Else");
            if(d1!=null && d1.getStatus()!=AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            d1.cancel(true);
            }

        }
        }
    });

vid2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Vid 2", "Vid 2");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            down d2=new down();
        if(vid2.getText().toString().equals("Start")){
            vid2.setText("Pause");
            d2.execute(url2,"two");


        }else if(vid2.getText().toString().equals("Pause")){
            vid2.setText("Start");
            Log.v("Vid 2 Else", "Vid 2 Else ");
            d2.cancel(true);
        }
        }
    });


}
private class down extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    RandomAccessFile output ;

    boolean cancel=false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.v("Pre Execute", "Pre Execute");
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        File outputFileCache=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/pau/"+params[1]+".mp4");

    try {

        Long download_ok = null ;
        int fileLength;
         URL url = new URL(params[0]);

         HttpURLConnection connection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection() ;


         if (outputFileCache.exists())
         {
             Log.v(">>>>>>", "Exists");
             connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
             connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + outputFileCache.length() + "-");
         }

         connection.setConnectTimeout(14000);
         connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
         connection.connect();

         if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2)
             throw new Exception("Invalid response code!");

         else
         {
             String connectionField = connection.getHeaderField("content-range");

             if (connectionField != null)
             {
                 String[] connectionRanges = connectionField.substring("bytes=".length()).split("-");
                 download_ok = Long.valueOf(connectionRanges[0]);
                 Log.v("download ok", ""+download_ok);
             }

             if (connectionField == null && outputFileCache.exists())
                 outputFileCache.delete();
if(download_ok==null){
download_ok=(long) 0;
}
             fileLength = (int) (connection.getContentLength() + download_ok);
             Log.v("file length", ""+fileLength);
             input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
             output = new RandomAccessFile(outputFileCache, "rw");
             output.seek(download_ok);

             byte data[] = new byte[1024];
             int count = 0;
             int __progress = 0;

             while ((count = input.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1 && __progress!=100) 
             {
                 Log.v(">>>>>>>>>>>progress cancelled", "<<<<<<<<<"+isCancelled());
                 if(isCancelled()){
                        Log.v(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", "<<<<<<<<<"+isCancelled());

                     break;
                 }else{
                     download_ok += count;

                 output.write(data, 0, count);

                 __progress = (int) ((download_ok * 100) / fileLength);
                 }

             }

             output.close();
             input.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
```

Comment: .cancel(true); 
Will only cancel the publishing of the progress of the task. Not the Task.

Comment: Then how can i stop downloading?

Comment: Do you get listener of pause button.?

Comment: @Sulabh What ever i done its all here.

Comment: Actually Hasham is plain wrong, Android does indeed attempt to cancel the execution of the task! Note that the cancel(boolean) methos returns a boolean, check that value, it is false if Android could not not stop the task for some reason.

Comment: Could you post here this `isCancelled()` method? I've used simillar construction but `isCancelled` was a boolean variable in my case.

Comment: Also, check if your Asynctask is calling onCancelled(), if the task was cancelled that method will be called instead of onPostExecute(..)

Comment: @soulreaver Yes, you can check that in while loop.

Comment: @Ernir: i'm not able to stop the task, and i also tried with onCanceled method too, no use.. :(

Comment: is your .cancel(boolean) returning true ?

Comment: @soulreaver it's `boolean isCancelled()` method from AsyncTask which the OP is using

Comment: @Ernir:i dont know, how to check that, using .cancel(true)

Comment: ex: boolean b = d1.cancel(true), then log the value of b

Comment: Yes its returning true @Ernir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your problem: You are creating a new instance of the Asynctask with every click, e.g.

`down d2=new down();`

This means that you are calling cancel on a different AsyncTask object. You need to move this line into your check for the start click and also use a field and not a local variable i.e.

```
 if(vid2.getText().toString().equals("Start")) {
     d2 = new down();
     vid2.setText("Pause");
     d2.execute(url2,"two");
}
```

where d2 is set in your class. Also note that class names should always start with capital letters, i.e. `class Down` instead of `class down`.

#### EDIT

You can store the Asynctask in a global class array that is equal in length to the number of videos.

```
Down downTasks[] = new Down[TOTAL VIDEOS];
```

Then you initialise the Views, similar to what you already did, here shown for one `View`

```
vid1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(vid1.getText().toString().equals("Start")){
            Log.v("Vid 1", "Vid 1");
            vid1.setText("Pause");
            downTasks[0] = new down();
            downTasks[0].execute(url1,"one");
        }
        else if(vid1.getText().toString().equals("Pause")){
            vid1.setText("Start");
            Log.v("Vid 1 Else", "Vid 1 Else");
            if(downTasks[0]!=null && downTasks[0].getStatus()!=AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
                downTasks[0].cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this code is quite redundant because you rewrite almost exactly the same code for every `View`, this can be nicely refactored with a `for` loop, but I leave that as an exercise for you if you feel like it.

Comment: This dos't work, i need to start multiple downloads and also resume multiple,

Comment: this is still the problem, you are calling `.cancel(boolean)` on a different AsyncTask instance, you have to rethink the structure of your code to store all the started AsyncTasks in your class so that you can reference the correct one when cancel is pressed.

Comment: I am confused. Can you explain in detail ?  How to store all the started AsyncTasks ? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry, i din't understand what you are saying,  and i done something related what you said, but dos't work.

Comment: What doesn´t work? I suggest updating your question with new code and a better formatted question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44762/discussion-between-pandiri-deepak-and-ernir-erlingsson)